# How to sort the nodes of Treeview where the nodes level property is 0 in .Net Winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, sorting, treeview

How to sort the nodes of Treeview where the nodes level property is 0 in .Net Winforms.
if there are child nodes available in for a level 0 nodes that should not be sorted.

Comment: You should **avoid** writing your whole question in **ALL CAPS** - this is generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, it's rude and offensive, and dramatically lowers your chances of folks taking their time to read your question and provide an answer. Don't do it - just don't .

Comment: And beyond that, more context on the question would be really helpful. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what is expected result, but...

I create an example with **6 Folders**: 4 empty and 2 non-empty:

[image]

As default, they sorted by name (alphabetically). As you said, the goal is to:

1. Sort only Level 0 nodes.
2. Do not sort Level 0 node if it has child nodes.

Because you didn't provide a way you want to sort Level 0 nodes, I choose to sort by *"Empty folders first, then non-empty"*. So I create custom sorter called `Level0NodeSorter`, which positions first Level 0 nodes without childs, then with them:

```
Public Class Level0NodeSorter
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer
        Dim node As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = TryCast(x, System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
        Return If(node.Level = 0 AndAlso node.Nodes.Count > 0, 1, 0)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then applied custom sorter to my `TreeView`:

```
treeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = New Level0NodeSorter()
treeView1.Sort()
```

And get this:

[image]

Empty folders positioned first. Then - non-empty. Childs not affected.

Comment: Thanks , i used the following logic

Comment: Public Class NodeSorter
 Implements System.Collections.IComparer

 Public Sub New()
 End Sub

 Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) _
  As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
  Dim tx As TreeNode = CType(x, TreeNode)
  Dim ty As TreeNode = CType(y, TreeNode)

 

  If (tx.Level = 0 And ty.Level = 0) Then
   Return String.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text)
  Else
   If (tx.Level = ty.Level) Then
    Return tx.Index - ty.Index
   Else
    Return 0
   End If
  End If


 End Function
End Class

Comment: You can create, use, combine any logic(s) you wish. Try different and get best one for yourself. And mark answer as helpful if it was so.